# How would I scan a directory to make links to pdfs using php?

Tags: php, file

I'm really new to PHP but what I want to do is make a dynamic table of contents for some of my companies job offerings.

So if i put all the pdfs of the job descriptions in a folder called ../jobops with the php file located in root directory what would I need to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php
  $directory = "/jobops";
  $contents = scandir($directory);
    if ($contents) {
       foreach($contents as $key => $value) {
             if ($value == "." || $value == "..") {
                unset($key);
             }
       }
    }
        echo "<ul>";
    foreach($contents as $k => $v) {
      echo "<li><a href=\"$directory/" . $v . "\">link text</a></li>";
    }
        echo "</ul>";

?>
```

Should work. Takes the directory, scans it, maps all the filenames into an array `$contents` removes the relative urls (the "." and "..") and then echoes them out.

Remember that `foreach` is relatively expensive, though; so you may wish to simply unset `$contents[0]` and `$contents[1]`.

---

Edited in response to the following (from the OP):

> Warning:
>   scandir(www.markonsolutions.com/jobops)
>   [function.scandir]: failed to open
>   dir: No such file or directory in
>   /home/content/t/i/m/timhish/html/test.php
>   on line 5 Warning: scandir()
>   [function.scandir]: (errno 2): No such
>   file or directory in
>   /home/content/t/i/m/timhish/h/i/s/h/html/test.php
>   on line 5 Warning: Invalid argument
>   supplied for foreach() in
>   /home/content/t/i/m/timhish/html/test.php
>   on line 15
>
> I changed ti from "/jobops"
>   thinking it was a relative directory
>   thing but apparently that's not it. also
>   im not sure what the
>   /home/content....... thing is but i am
>   currently hosted with go daddy maybe
>   thats how they store things?

The `$directory` variable is relative to where the script is being called. In my case, this runs from the root folder so it *should* be, for me, `$directory = "jobops"` assuming the folder and script are stored in the same place. Without knowing your server's directory structure I can't really help you, but I would suggest ruling out a problem with the `scandir()` function.

To do this, create a folder in the same directory as your script called whatever you like, populate it with at least one image (so that the following `if()` doesn't unset the entire array) and see if that works. If it *does* then you're stuck with finding the relative path to your folder. If it *doesn't* then I'm stuck myself.

Comment: sweet thanks I'm trying it now (ill have to tweak it a little) can you explain more about the unset I don't follow?

Comment: The `unset($key)` unsets the variables (`$content[0]` and `$content[1]`. If you omit the `unset()` step you'll see what it removes, and why (I think) you should.

Comment: Warning: scandir(www.markonsolutions.com/jobops) [function.scandir]: failed to open dir: No such file or directory in /home/content/t/i/m/timhish/html/test.php on line 5

Warning: scandir() [function.scandir]: (errno 2): No such file or directory in /home/content/t/i/m/timhish/html/test.php on line 5


      Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/content/t/i/m/timhish/html/test.php on line 15

Comment: I changed ti from "/jobops" thinking it was a relative direcotry thing but apprently thats not it. also im not sure what the /home/content....... thing is but i am currently hosted with go daddy maybe thats how they store things?

Answer (score 3):

The [SPL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php) (PHP5) provides a nice interface to directory traversal:

```
// whitelist of valid file types (extension => display name)
$valid = array(
    'pdf' => 'PDF',
    'doc' => 'Word'
);

$files = array();    

$dir = new DirectoryIterator($directory_path);

foreach($dir as $file)
{
    // filter out directories
    if($file->isDot() || !$file->isFile()) continue;

    // Use pathinfo to get the file extension
    $info = pathinfo($file->getPathname());

    // Check there is an extension and it is in the whitelist
    if(isset($info['extension']) && isset($valid[$info['extension']])) 
    {
        $files[] = array(
            'filename' => $file->getFilename(),
            'size' => $file->getSize(),
            'type' => $valid[$info['extension']], // 'PDF' or 'Word'
            'created' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $file->getCTime())
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /home/content/t/i/m/timhish/html/test.php on line 24

Comment: Just needed an extra bracket on that second if statement

Answer (score 2):

take a look at [fnmatch()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fnmatch.php) or [glob()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) functions.

(i'd have liked to post it as a comment, but the link would have been too long)

Comment: i read in your link that glob can replace opendir but how would it knwo which dircotry to point at?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  // open this directory 
$myDirectory = opendir(".");

// get each entry
while($entryName = readdir($myDirectory)) {
    $dirArray[] = $entryName;
}

// close directory
closedir($myDirectory);

//  count elements in array
$indexCount = count($dirArray);
Print ("$indexCount files<br>\n");

// sort 'em
sort($dirArray);

// print 'em
print("<TABLE border=1 cellpadding=5 cellspacing=0 class=whitelinks>\n");
print("<TR><TH>Filename</TH><th>Filetype</th><th>Filesize</th></TR>\n");
// loop through the array of files and print them all
for($index=0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) {
        if (substr("$dirArray[$index]", 0, 1) != "."){ // don't list hidden files
        print("<TR><TD><a href=\"$dirArray[$index]\">$dirArray[$index]</a></td>");
        print("<td>");
        print(filetype($dirArray[$index]));
        print("</td>");
        print("<td>");
        print(filesize($dirArray[$index]));
        print("</td>");
        print("</TR>\n");
    }
}
print("</TABLE>\n");


?>
```

seems to be working but I need to tweak it to only search a sub dir and only *.pdf files